# 15.04 Server fails to update with failed to fetch temporary failure resolving errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 15.04, update-manager

I can't do `sudo apt-get update`; when I try it gives me loads of failed to fetch everything. I have no idea what could be wrong. I searched for what the `sources.list` file should look like and it looks the same to me.

```
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease
Err http://nl.security.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease
Err http://nl.security.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'nl.security.ubuntu.com' Err http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com' Err http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com' Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com' Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com' Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com' Reading package lists... Done W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid-updates/Release.gpg Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/vivid/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead..
```

Comment: That looks like your network connection and/or dns.  Is port 52 and 53 open for DNS traffic? Maybe try a different dns server.

Comment: I am connecting through openSSH so i guess i have an internet connection. I don't know if those ports are open, how can i check in terminal?

Comment: Still not working with google DNS

Comment: Correction, @mchid it does work now, rebooted the network card. Thanks a lot!

Comment: for future reference, you can check ufw status by running the following command:  `sudo ufw status verbose`

Answer (score 1):

I changed default DNS server to the Google DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Now I can install everything again.